# Angular 1.6.6 catch event for refresh $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

Sometimes an event occurs on the page that clears $rootScope. More precisely, it returns to its initial state. In this case, the event occurs when switching between browser tabs! O_o Here it is worth clarifying that a response from the socket is expected on the page. And weird behavior is observed when we return to the tab after the socket response event.

I have already tried to catch the changes on the locationChangeStart and routeChangeStart, but no results.